# LINQ Group By Clause Dynamic

Tags: linq, group-by

```
var query = trafficHandler.portList
            .Join(
            trafficHandler.timeList,
            p => p.PortId,
            t => t.PortId,
            (p, t) => new { Port = p, Time = t })
            .Join(
            trafficHandler.trafficList,
            pt => pt.Time.TimeId,
            tr => tr.TimeId,
            (pt, tr) => new { Port = pt.Port, Time = pt.Time, Traffic = tr })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Port.PortNumber,
                x.Time.TimeNumber,
                x.Time.DayNumber,
                x.Traffic.Action,
                x.Traffic.User
            })
            .Where(x => allowedPort.Contains(x.PortNumber) && allowedDay.Contains(x.DayNumber) && allowedTime.Contains(x.TimeNumber) && allowedUser.Contains(x.User) && allowedAction.Contains(x.Action))
            .GroupBy(y => new { y.DayNumber, y.TimeNumber, y.User })
            .Where(z => z.Count() >= baseline)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key.DayNumber)
            .ThenBy(g => g.Key.TimeNumber)
            .ThenBy(g => g.Key.User);
```

how do I dynamically allow certain column able to put in group by? Like sometimes I need y.Action to include in the Group By clause as well, I don't want to rewrite every LINQ query that will be a lot of redundant function. Read some of the other similar questions asked on Stack Overflow, seems like you will need dynamic LINQ library, is there other way around it?

Comment: GroupBy(y => new { PortNumber = groupByClause[0] ? y.PortNumber : 0, DayNumber = groupByClause[1] ? y.DayNumber : 0, TimeNumber = groupByClause[2] ? y.TimeNumber : 0, User = groupByClause[3] ? y.User : 0, Action = groupByClause[4] ? y.Action : 0 }), 

somehow I managed to done this using boolean, not sure if there will be any bug

Comment: @Inumane: add it to your question